# Linker error: /* item instance */ already defined in item.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, constructor, linker-errors, destructor

I'm writing a program in c++ trying to implement a linked list and I'm getting a linker error in reference to one of my constructors and destructors (both of the same class). The class is called item. It's an assignment for CS260 and I'm not allowed to edit anything in main.cpp .

These are the error messages when I try to build it:

1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall item::item(char *,double)" (??0item@@QAE@PADN@Z) already defined in main.obj

1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall item::~item(void)" (??1item@@UAE@XZ) already defined in main.obj

1>C:\Users\Molly\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lab1\Debug\Lab1.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

When I edited out both the constructor and destructor the program built. I'm not sure where or how the info in the constructor/destructor have already been defined.

Here is my item.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>


class item
{
public:
    // Item needs a construtor that takes in a char* name and a double weight   

    item(char * name, double weight);

    virtual ~item(void); // destructor

    char * GetName() const {return name;}
    const double GetWeight() const { return weight; }

private:
    char *name;     // name of the item
    double weight;  // keeps track of weight of that/those item(s)

};
```

Here is my item.cpp file:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "item.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

item::item(char * name, double weight) 
{
    name = NULL;
    weight = 0;

    if (this->name)
        delete[] this->name;
    this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(this->name, name);

}

item::~item()
{
    if (name)
        delete[] name;
}
```

Finally, this is the main.cpp file provided by my instructor that cannot be edited.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "item.h"
#include "item.cpp"
#include "inventory.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

void AddItem(inventory& inv, char* name, double weight)
{
    cout << "Adding " << name << " with a weight of " << weight << "." << endl;
    inv.AddItem(item(name, weight));
}

void RemoveItem(inventory& inv, char* name)
{
    cout << "Removing " << name << "." << endl;
    inv.RemoveItem(name);
}

void doTestBasic()
{
    inventory inv;

    // Make sure printing an empty inventory works
    //inv.PrintInventory();

    // Make sure adding the first one works
    AddItem(inv, "helmet", 5);
    inv.PrintInventory();

    // Note to stackoverflow: there was some node adding/removing stuff
    // in here (and in doTestAdvanced/ doTestBadData that I removed because it's not pertinent 

}

void doTestAdvanced()
{
    inventory inv;

// Add items with different case
AddItem(inv, "helmet", 1.0);
AddItem(inv, "Helmet", 1.0);
AddItem(inv, "HELMET", 1.0);
inv.PrintInventory();

// Remove items with case insensitivity
RemoveItem(inv, "HELMET");
inv.PrintInventory();

}

void doTestBadData()
{
    inventory inv(50);

    // Adding too much
    AddItem(inv, "bag of gold coins", 50);  // should work
    AddItem(inv, "feather", 0.1);               // should fail
    inv.PrintInventory();
    RemoveItem(inv, "bag of gold coins");   // should work
    inv.PrintInventory();

    // Using long strings
    AddItem(inv, "this is such a long item and nothing should have a name             thing long but we have no guarantee that some crazy person wouldn't make such an item and then we need to make sure our program doesn't break.  Hint: don't use char[] to store data.  Only use char*.", 1.0);
    inv.PrintInventory();
}

int main() {

    doTestBasic();
    doTestAdvanced();
    doTestBadData();

#ifdef _WIN32
    if (_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()) {
        cout << "Memory leaks!" << endl;
    }
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated. I'm not confident with constructors and destructors and as such I have no idea where I'm going wrong or why I'm getting those linker errors. Thank you!

Comment: `#include "item.cpp"` Never include cpp files.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
#include "item.h"
#include "item.cpp" // <--
```

is wrong. You only include *header* files. The way you get your definitions in is you compile `item.cpp` and then compile `main.cpp` and then link them together.

Comment: And the *reason* is that `#include` will "paste" the contents of the file at that location.

Comment: wow. thank you so much. that was in the file that my instructor provided to us. I didn't even think to check it because I assumed there wouldn't be mistakes. It builds now.